# Jquery .show does not change display property

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am generating script that is supposed to select values after page got reloaded with <kbd>F5</kbd> or browser back button.

JQuery is loaded, and element is on the page, screenshot below shows me running in console `$('.isEstateOver325K').show()` and element remaining `display:none`.

[image]

I must be missing something obvious here.

script that is supposed to change visibility is fired by another that triggers `change` and `click` on element it would be weird if this would be the reason since it works ok for some different elements - still worth mentioning.

```
(function() {

$(
    "[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Divorced'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Co-habiting']"
).closest('.quote-form__question').click(function() {
    if ($(
            "[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Divorced'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Co-habiting']"
        ).is(':checked')) {
        $(".isEstateOver325K").show();
        $(".isEstateOver325K").addClass('quote-form--active');
    } else {
        $(".isEstateOver325K").hide();
    }
});

});
$(function() {
    $("[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single']").trigger("click");
    $("[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single']").trigger("change");
});
```

**I am sure someone has experienced something similar, why doesn't it change to `display:block`?**

Comment: could you provide some kind of jsfiddle or sth ?

Comment: Mouse events will not work on hidden elements.

Comment: @FerTo I am sure I will get answer without it if not in 5 minutes will add one.

Comment: @JohnR but it did trigger event and stepped into event handler, check screenshot.

Comment: Are you saying the item doesn't show or that the `style="display:none"` doesn't go when you look at the markup? Because `show()` won't remove the `style` attribute.

Comment: I think your inline display:none is the issue

Comment: @Liam nether nor item shows nor running in console $('').show changes display.

Comment: So it's does not appear in the markup? You must have something overidding the display then. Without a full example it's going ot be hard to debug

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius  can you provide html code or add jsfiddle in que so that we can check.?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Did click event getting trigger after hiding the element?

Comment: As I said, in some specific circumstances (and maybe you have more CSS selectors also having display:none ?) .show() isn't able to make display:none to display:block, therefore try CSS instead inline. And @MatasVaitkevicius it would really make things easier to understand with sort of jsbin and do you really want "$('').show() ?"

Comment: @FerTo the point of question is why would $('').show wouldn't change display you can see me running commands from console in screenshot attached and nothing happening.

Comment: Well you are calling nothing. Did you executed $('') in your console? It is returning an empty array. You need to tell jQuery Selector what you want. Try out http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/ $("*").show()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with :

```
$('').attr('style','display:block;')
```

Comment: Good job, didn't expect this to work, but it did it. Must be something with jquery being half loaded or having some rule around `show() hide()` Would appreciate if you could point to where are you coming from. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `toggle()`. Toggle will toggle display:none to display:block and Vice-Versa.

```
 $(
    "[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Divorced'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Co-habiting']"
).closest('.quote-form__question').click(function() {
    if ($(
            "[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Divorced'],[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Co-habiting']"
        ).is(':checked')) {
        $(".isEstateOver325K").toggle();
        $(".isEstateOver325K").addClass('quote-form--active');
    } else {
        $(".isEstateOver325K").toggle();
    }
});

});
$(function() {
    $("[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single']").trigger("click");
    $("[name='MaritalStatus'][value='Single']").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: toggle is not an option there are different selectors that could trigger event to fire.

Answer (score 0):

even this can also work

```css
/*---for multiple css property-----*/
$('').css({
  'display':'block'
});

/*---for single css property-----*/
$('').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

So for your first question, to sum up . If you call

```
$('').show();
```

You're telling jQuery to select "nothing" and to show this "nothing".

If you want to select "all". Than you have to use the all-selector(http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/):

```
$('*').show();
```

A really basic example is here: http://jsbin.com/cixoxatufu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

And for the rest, I really appreciate a JSBin or something as this is just hinting to something and not really providing a solution.